# SUM of multiple activecell rows

Tags: excel, vba

I was able to get the calculations between specific columns in a table in the active cell row.
But I could not find a way to get calculations between multiple active cell rows.It is only calculating from the last row that i clicked on and ignores the previous one.

I'd like to be able to click on any column and still get the values needed because I need to calculate multiple values

Here's the closest code I have.
I have tried using other equations and formulas but only "SUM" is working for this format.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Sheet1.Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(" & Sheet1.Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Address(False, False) & "," & _
Sheet1.Range("K" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Address(False, False) & ")"
End Sub
```

Snip of the desired output is attached
[IMAGE OF THE DESIRED OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8ha5.png)

Many thanks

Comment: I have been on this situation coming back and forth for a month now. Thank you for your patience :D

Answer (score 0):

try

updated to intersect with column W only

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim selectedSum As Double
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("W"))
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        selectedSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
        Me.Range("C11").Value = selectedSum
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. The code works. Almost there, but not exactly what I needed. I tried to play around with your code to achieve my goal but I had no luck.
Would you be able to workaround your code and specifically target the value from column W only regardless of what column I click on? Many thanks

Comment: @LeiNadal see updated code using `Me.Columns("W")`

Comment: doesnt work as well :/

Comment: @Susmaryosep from my testing selecting one or more cells in column W will show the sum of selected cells in C11, is that not your desired result? can you explain in detail what you are doing that does not work well?

Comment: I apologize for lack of details. The code works if you directly click on column W. Id like to be able to click on any column and still get values because I want to do it in multiple columns at the same time.

Comment: I have edited the main question with better details.

Comment: @Susmaryosep that was what my first code was doing but you said to target the column W values, read your first comment on this post of mine, before the code was using `Me.UsedRange` to target any used cell in the sheet, then as per your request i changed it to `Me.Columns("W")`

Answer (score 0):

The code bellow will trigger everywhere you click within your worksheet, and write the Sum of column W in cell "C11":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim LastRow As Long, SumRng As Range
    Dim MySum As Double
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row '  get last row with data in column W
    Set SumRng = Range("W1:W" & LastRow) ' set the range object
  
    MySum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumRng)
    Range("C11").Value = MySum
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: ty for your help. code does not work. value doesnt change and i cant seem to find where the values are coming from